# How to Pass Object to ViewModel when its constructing in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, dependencies

i Have ViewModel

```
public class VM: DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(VM), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public int Length 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Text != null ? Text.Length : 0;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and View for it

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:VM Text="{Binding ControlText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

yes, view has also dependency property in code behind

```
    public string ControlText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ControlText", typeof(string), typeof(Writer), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

I got error on Output Log

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ControlText; DataItem=null; target element is 'VM' (HashCode=21019086); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

when this technic works, i will be have tools to construct my viewmodel.
maybe anyone know how to bind this view property to viewmodel property or know technic how to do it properly :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be somewhat confused with a few things. If you want to set your view model as the `UserControl.DataContext` in XAML, that is ok, but you don't data bind to controls from there:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:VM  />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Next, if the view model is set as the `UserControl.DataContext`, then you can access its properties from the XAML in the `UserControl` like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now if you want to access the `ControlText` property from the XAML, then *that* is when you need to use the `RelativeSource Binding`. However, notice how you should reference your `UserControl`, by its name/type and *not* using `UserControl` because as your error says, there is no `ControlText` property defined in `UserControl`. Try this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ControlText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={x:Type local:YourUserControl}} />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Finally, if you want to data bind to the `ControlText` property of your control from *outside* the control, then you could do that like this:

```
<local:YourUserControl ControlText="{Binding SomeStringProperty}" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

When using MVVM, we generally *don't* try to pass data from one data source through a `UIElement` to another data source. Instead, we prefer to pass the data from one data item to another data item. Your problem is that you are instantiating your view model in the view... instead, instantiate it in a parent view model and pass in whatever values you want and then set it as the `UserControl.DataContext` property value from *outside* the control in the parent view:

```
<local:YourUserControl DataContext="{Binding YourChildViewModelPropertyInParentVM}" />
```

Once you have the correct values in the view model, then you shouldn't need the `ControlText` property.

Comment: i know at,
and the last feaute which you shows me is the main reason why i make Dependency property In Writer (UserCntrol).
but i want to make somethink like that:
i have string property
string s{get; set;}
i create Writer (UserControl) and i pass this string through binding to created usercontrol.
<local:Writer ControlText="{Binding s}"/>
now i want a UserCOntrol to pass out the property s into Viewmodel.
so i trying to do in Writer.xaml
<viewmodels.VM s="{Binding s}" Relative=.../>
thats the point of constructing Viewmodel throught views.
property s was draging throught
view to viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `DataContext` in XAML, it will be initialized at time of XAML loading. Also, `VM` doesn't lie in Visual Tree as that of UserControl so `RelativeSource` can't work here.

But you can do that in code behind by setting DataContext from UserControl's constructor and do binding there itself:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   VM viewModel = new VM();
   DataContext = viewModel;
   Binding binding = new Binding("ControlText") { Source = this };
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(viewModel, VM.TextProperty, binding);
}
```